# Process that needs a volume starting before volume mounts

Tags: 11.04, server, mount, crashplan

The destination for incoming CrashPlan backups on my server (11.04) is

/media/SeagateBig

(SeagateBig is the volume name of my 2TB USB drive).

When the server boots, two things happen: 1) SeagateBig auto-mounts and 2) CrashPlan starts.

The problem is, that often these two things don't happen in that order.  Then I get:

- Crashplan starts
- looks for /media/SeagateBig
- doesn't find it
- instead of waiting for it, CREATES IT

Now it's backing up onto my / filesystem.  NOT COOL.

Meanwhile, when SeagateBig finally gets around to mounting, it finds that /media/SeagateBig already exists, shrugs, and creates /media/SeagateBig_ as its mount point.

What I need is a way for the order to be enforced - where SeagateBig mounts and then and only then the CrashPlan service is started.

Unless I learn that CrashPlan can be told to wait for its destination directory, never to create it... which I am also investigating.  But the CrashPlanEngine script is installed by the product so I am loath to modify it, as I know I could by having it loop until df greps successfully for "SeagateBig".

UPDATE: More research has led to asking a better question.  See [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84547/local-fs-not-including-all-drives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how Crashplan works, but here are some tips:

- If it has an automatically startup plan, disable it, and find out which is the executable for Crashplan.
- Then create a shell script that looks like this:

  ```
  \#!bin/bash

  sleep 30 && >name of executable<;
  ```

Note: This will stop the execution for 30 seconds. You can use whatever time

name your script start_crashplan.sh

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x start_crashplan.sh
```

Then add your script in the startup.

Sorry if I was of the subject, but I think this way you have maximum control of what you start and when.

Comment: This is kind of where I don't want to go -- I am trying not to break CrashPlan so that when they send an update it still works.  I see that the script that starts CrashPlan has $local_fs and $remote_fs in the LSB but it's running ahead of the mounting of devices in /etc/mtab ANYWAY.

Comment: Just heard from CrashPlan support -- they said, "Modify the script."  *sigh*

Comment: :) What can you do, sometimes you need to get your hands dirty.