# $local_fs not including all drives

Tags: 11.04, server, mount, startup, crashplan

This is a refinement of [a question I asked yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84176/process-that-needs-a-volume-starting-before-volume-mounts), the product of deeper research I have done since.

The script that starts CrashPlan has, as it should, a hard dependency on $local_fs in its LSB Required-Start entry.  The problem is coming about when this dependency is satisfied without the USB volume being mounted.  Therefore CrashPlan thinks it has to create its backup destination and the conflicts begin.

My understanding of $local_fs is that everything in mtab will be mounted before it is satisfied.  Is that not the case?  Are there options I can add to the mtab entry to change this behavior for the volume in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, USB drives are mounted by udev after virtual-filesystems (an Upstart signal), not as part of $local_fs.

So one solution is a bug against CrashPlan - it's assuming the drive you want to backup is not USB.

A workaround is to change the dependency (or to add a second) is the CrashPlan init script.

Another (easier) workaround is to add a 'sleep 60' or other pause to the CrashPlan init script. Or to simply renumber the symlinks so they run later.

Comment: I am trying so hard not to modify the CrashPlan script but I am starting to see how difficult that will be.  Looks like the simplest thing will be to add $all as a dependency just until they fix their bug.

Comment: <*sigh*> CrashPlan support said, Modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

Upstart should be able to handle this if you convert to a standard upstart script. I've tried the following, but not had any success so far.. perhaps it's a start of an answer though...

1. read http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook
2. disable /etc/init.d/crashplan
3. create /etc/init/crashplan.conf with content similar to the following:

   description "crashplan on usbhdd"
   author ""

   start on mounted MOUNTPOINT=/media/USB-HDD
   stop on runlevel [016]

   pre-start script
       /usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanEngine start
   end script

   post-stop script
       /usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanEngine stop
   end script